# Is there a way to have mp3 playing throughout Web site continually?

Tags: php, jquery, jplayer

I would like an audio player on my site that can play continuously while other pages of site are loaded and viewed. Is it done by a module, or where it is placed on site?
i am currently using jquery and jplayer to play music on my site and all pages are dynamically linked with php.
basically my site is an audio streaming site that have many albums and music files across different pages on my site and i really wanted jplayer to always sits at bottom through out of the site and when someone clicks the album's track jplayer starting playing it and user able to listen his played songs even he browse new pages on the site.
p.s: just like spotify and other online streaming sites.
any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The proper way to do this is to never reload the page and instead fetch all new content via AJAX.

Comment: load your page using ajax

Comment: how to load pages by using ajax? any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the music player continually play throughout the navigation of the site, you will need to call each page via AJAX, this way the browser actually never reloads.  A simple example can found on this jsfiddle [link here](http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/WQXXT/)

```
$.ajax({
    url:'dance-albums.php',
    success: function (response) {
        $('#output').html(response);
    },
    error: function () {

    },
});
```

In this scenerio, I imagine you will have a music playing by default on the toolbar player?  If you have different songs that you want the user to play, you can create a function on the the link which will call jPlayer("setMedia",media) and it should play with the mp3 parameter you will provide.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, i have this [vertical  menu] (http://pastebin.com/rN96KhJY) that is included on every page with php and i also have some php function that ensures the current selected menu state so my questions are where should i put this code and i also don't want to affect my selected links state either!

Answer (score 1):

Build a single page app. There are many good javascript frameworks that can make this easier, like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) or [Ember](http://emberjs.com/)

Comment: is there a alternate way because i already develop more than 80% of site and added contents to several pages. if i go for any of frameworks you have suggested then how much time and effort i must have to put ? what do you suggests?